# How to update the view from a viewmodel in WPF using MVVM design

Tags: mvvm

I am using the WFP with MVVM design for my first project and I am having the problem to update the view after I process a command from client to update the entity. At this time,  the view can talks to the viewmodel but the viewmodel could not talk back to view.
Anyone has any idea how to make this works?
Thanks, 
Jdang

Comment: Very sorry, but Have you solved this problem? I stuck in the same..

Answer (score 4):

You should make the ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event when the ViewModel properties change. Assuming that the UI is bound to the ViewModel properties this should work.

Answer (score 3):

In a typical MVVM application, you use bindings to connect the view to the ViewModel. Bindings are automatically updated when the ViewModel raises the `PropertyChanged` event, defined by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. So you need to implement that interface in the ViewModel and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the value of a property is changed, and the view will reflect the change automatically.

Comment: Yes, I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event but nothing changes on the view. Do I have to do anything special on view. Currently here is what I have

Comment: Yes, I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event but nothing changes on the view. Do I have to do anything special on view. Currently here is what I have for my xaml Text="{Binding User.UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". Do you have any example for me to take a look?

Comment: It should work with what you have... Could you edit your question to include more code?

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to the MVVM Pattern, I recommend the following as excellent resources from MSDN that cover both the pattern and how to implement it in WPF and Silverlight applications:

1. [Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)
2. [Advanced MVVM Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)

Based on what you have said, it sounds like you might want to review [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec6), and how you can leverage the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), and [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) interfaces to enable two-way communication between your views and view models.

*Silverlight and WPF data binding supports multiple data binding modes. With one-way data binding, UI controls can be bound to a view model so that they reflect the value of the underlying data when the display is rendered. Two-way data binding will also automatically update the underlying data when the user modifies it in the UI. To ensure that the UI is kept up to date when the data changes in the view model, it should implement the appropriate change notification interface.*

Comment: Yes, I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event but nothing changes on the view. Do I have to do anything special on view. Currently here is what I have  Text="{Binding User.UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: Your binding appears to be correct. Have you verified that PropertyChanged is being raised when the UserName property is changed by setting a breakpoint? Also, double check that the textual name of the property you are raising to the event exactly matches your property name. Post your view and view model if you want, that would help debug your issue.

Answer (score 2):

*In addition* to the other answers, I would also suggest having your ViewModels extend [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx).

Some people believe DependencyObjects are heavy weight (and they can be, if you create thousands of instances of them) and a bit complex for new users (most definitely there are situations where this is true).  There are, however, other advantages to DependencyObjects, such as automatic support for property change notification and speed of binding evaluation.

Here's my DP snippet (save as DependencyProperty.snippet in C:\Users[YOUR NAME HERE]\Documents\Visual Studio [2010, 2008]\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SnippetFile1</Title>
      <Author>will</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>dp</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>PropertyName</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
          <Default>PropertyName</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="false">
          <ID>ClassName</ID>
          <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
          <Default>ClassName</Default>
          <Function>ClassName()</Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
          <Default>object</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>DefaultValue</ID>
          <ToolTip>Default value</ToolTip>
          <Default>null</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[#region $PropertyName$
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for <see cref="$PropertyName$"/>.
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty $PropertyName$Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        $PropertyName$Name, 
        typeof($Type$), 
        typeof($ClassName$), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata($DefaultValue$));

/// <summary>
/// The name of the <see cref="$PropertyName$"/> <see cref="DependencyProperty"/>.
/// </summary>
public const string $PropertyName$Name = "$PropertyName$";

/// <summary>
/// $end$
/// </summary>
public $Type$ $PropertyName$
{
    get { return ($Type$)GetValue($PropertyName$Property); }
    set { SetValue($PropertyName$Property, value); }
}
#endregion  ]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: I agree you get some performance benefits using a DependencyObject, but they are bound to the thread they were created on and dependency objects are not serializable. In certain cases they are definitely the way to go, but in general it is safer (and still relatively performant) to use a POCO with the notification interfaces.

Comment: For those interested, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#HowDataBindingReferencesAreResolved provides decent information on the performance implications Will is talking about.